# Labeling in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, labeling

I have a problem in labeling.Labels of near by points get overlapping.If I use spacearound option label of any of the poi displays[image]

In the above picture Bank of Baroda and Central bank of India get overlapped.I want to display the label of Bank of Baroda into left side of the point.I used maxdisplacement option.But still it is not working.

I used the following otion in my SLD

```
"maxDisplacement"=15
```

"spaceAround"=-1

Is there any option in geoserver that change the position of the label automatically when it gets overlapped

Answer (score 2):

The [Geoserver documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html#overlapping-and-separating-labels-spacearound) says:

> By default GeoServer will not render labels “on top of each other”. By using the spaceAround option you can either allow labels to overlap, or add extra space around labels

You are using a negative value for `spaceAround`.

You should use a positive amount. You can only find the ideal value by trial and error. I'll start with 5 and then play around with the value to get the optimal value.

Comment: If I use spaceAround with positive value label wont be display in the last zoom level.Because points are so near.

Comment: making sure that all labels are seen, and that they do not overlap, are two competing requirements, and come at a cost of each other. You need to compromise somewhere.

Comment: I want to know what will be the value of maxDisplacement.

Comment: It will be whatever you supply in the SLD